# Access to measures in custom sonarqube rule (java check)

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

Hi I'm writing my own plugin for Sonarqube with custom rule checks. The rules should report issues based on some measurements on methods or classes. The key of this approach is accessing measures of related metrics.  Here is my sample check class :

```
@Rule(key = "BrainMethod", name = "Brain method"
public class BrainMethod extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {
     private JavaFileScannerContext context;
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaFileScanner#scanFile(org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaFileScannerContext)
 */
@Override
public void scanFile(JavaFileScannerContext context) {
    this.context = context;
   //scan the java file tree
    scan(context.getTree());
}

  /* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor#visitMethod(org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.MethodTree)
 */
@Override
  public void visitMethod(MethodTree tree) {
    // here is the place where I want to acces to the measurements
    context.reportIssue(this, tree, String.format("Potentional brain method"));
    super.visitMethod(tree);
  }
```

Is there any way how to get the measured values of metrics such as lines of code, complexity or others in this rule? Or am I using a wrong approach for doing that?

Comment: For what language are you writing custom rules?

Comment: The plugin analyzes Java code.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: For example I want to access to the lines of code metric for method which i am visiting. In general I am asking if there is a way to use one of the CoreMetrics in this visitor method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such feature, it's the responsibility of your custom rules to compute what is required. You can find some utility methods like `context.getComplexityNodes(methodTree);` but in that's a kind of corner case.

Comment: So if I understand it is a wrong approach to achieve that. Is there any option how to compute aggregate metrics (using other metrics) for  each method, classs .. and define it as a rule?